# Initialize array of unnamed function pointers each from a seperate file

Tags: c++

I have somewhat of a challenge from my professor to solve 200ish c++ brain teaser problems that are all relatively small. However, I do not want create 200 c++ projects, one for every function. So I wanted to have a static array of void functions which then a central program can choose which one to call. I could just name each function manually and prototype all 200 of them into a header but that seems like bad practice.

And I really don't care about the name of the function, only it's index, since the problems are referred to by number.

I was hoping to keep the array creation outside of the main function, and it'd seem right to have it calculated at compile time, but I guess since the functions aren't loaded into memory at compile time, there's no way for the pointers in the array to be constant. Yet somehow putting the functions into an array initializer by name just works? eg `void (* arr [])() = { foo, bar, sum };` But this requires I name and prototype every single function.

I've seen answers about creating a low-Level function registry, but that involves modifying the linker which seems going to far for something I want to be able to send to my professor.

I've seen answers that use a classes constructor to run code to add the function to the array, but that creates and deletes an unnecessary class instance for every single function.

I've seen answers which use global initialization to call a function before main that adds a function to the array, but this creates a unnecessary dummy value that's wasting memory.

I've seen answers use many many confusing templates, and that just seems way to much to do something that seems as simple as this, and to much to explain to my professor.

`constexpr` or something along the like seems to be the way to go, but also seems like it won't just run some code, but I'm unfamiliar with using it. And I'm okay with using newer features like `consteval` from the 20 standard.

All in all, it seems I just want to be able to run a line of code, like `funcs[X] = [](){ ... }` before main but also in a separate file, because putting all 200 funcs in one file would be a mess. But if there's any other way to init a single element of an array at a time from separate files at compile time, that'd be great.

Comment: Since you have a very simple prototype, look into [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). A simple lambda will collapse into a function pointer so you could define the functions inside the array definition. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/b9nPMYh4v

Comment: And even if you make them into functions, you don't need to prototype them. Just define the functions before your array.

Comment: You can create an array of function pointers that point to lambdas, something like `void (* arr [])() = { [](){...}, [](){...}, ... };` But frankly I don't think it will buy you anything except perhaps some headache at debug time.

Comment: user4581301 and (n. m. could be an AI), yes but the main goal here is to not put all the functions in the same file, as there are 200ish of them.
And by defining the functions inside the same array init, it'd all be one statement and file.

Comment: I fear, this is not what you are looking for https://godbolt.org/z/rvK5dcc3z !? This is a single file solution :(  When using template function you would implement them in header files, but that means you would have to include them all (although you might chain inclusion). By "separate files" you referred to "separate compilation units"? In that case you might think about static initialisation instead of constexpr, but be sure to avoid the "static initialisation order fiasco"!

Comment: You cannot have something in one file and reference it in another file without it having a name.